# How to trigger a single initial action in many redux reducers at once?

Tags: redux

I am refactoring my app to use `redux`, and it's great.

One thing I'd like to do is to dispatch an initial action at the beginning, and every reducer would manage to initialize themselves at that moment.

Let's say i have a `main.js` that create the stores, the routes, etc. In that file, I could do:

```
store.dispatch({ type: 'app/init' });
```

If I do this, the action type `app/init` can be intercepted in each reducer which needs to initialize itself.

**An example use case (among others)**

When the app is launched, a third party library must be called to see if a user is currently authenticated. If so, a `LOGIN_SUCCESS` action must be triggered with that user data.

I'd like to see this code in the same file as the authentication reducer, triggered by a global init action (which would mean the store is created).

**The problem**

In the reducer (where init action is managed), other actions cannot be dispatched.

The advised way of implementing actions is by defining *action creators*, which is indeed very clean, and let us use middleware like `thunks` to dispatch other actions.

I could use `init()` action creators for each reducer (I define related actions and reducer in the same "ducks" file), but that means importing/calling each of them in `main.js`, which is what I was trying to avoid by dispatching the action directly.

**How to get the best of all worlds by having one single `app/init` action dispatched, and being able to intercept it in each store and dispatch other actions?**

*Note: I thougth of just implementing those initialization code in each reducer, inline, but I do not have standard access to the dispatcher that way?*

Comment: Are you trying to prime the state at the beginning?

Comment: There is already an initial state which is defined in each reducer. Then, based on that initial state, other actions need to be dispatched. A bit like an initial thunk... which i'd like to group in a single dispatch intercepted by all reducers that needs it.

Comment: `createStore` takes an `initialState` as an optional parameter.  If you are just trying to set the initial state for the whole app, this is worth checking out.  This is preferable to a set of initial actions that are fired.

Comment: Agree, but how would you dispatch an action based on that state, at that initial moment? Those `initialState` objects are defined before the store even exists. Give me a minute to add an example in the question, to make is less abstract.

Comment: I would look toward a solution whereby each connected component gets its own initial state through an action called in `ComponentDidMount`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment... but I'd like to replace those many specific actions, which are potentially less performant, and less maintainable, by a single generic one.

Answer (score 1):

The reducer just calculates the next state based on an action. In Redux, it’s not the right place to put side effects like calling an API.

If you want to orchestrate an asynchronous workflow of actions, I suggest you to look at [Redux Saga](http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/). It lets you define long-running functions (“sagas”) that can “wait” for specific actions, execute some side effects, and dispatch more actions.